# Can't start the Play Framework application

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I am using `2.5.x` play framework and here is my `application.conf`

```
play.http.secret.key="changeme"
play.i18n.langs = [ "en", "en-US", "fr" ]
.....
.....
```

When I am trying to run the application using following command

```
go-1.1/bin/go -Dplay.http.secret.key=abcdefghij -Dhttp.port=9999
```

It's throwing me an error:

```
at play.api.libs.crypto.CryptoConfigParser.get$lzycompute(Crypto.scala:498)
at play.api.libs.crypto.CryptoConfigParser.get(Crypto.scala:465)
at play.api.libs.crypto.CryptoConfigParser.get(Crypto.scala:463)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
at com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:62)
at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:104)

....
```

If I am checking `crypto.scala:498` then it's clearly saying "Application secret key is not found". I am already providing the key in `command line` and `applicaiton.conf`. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

What we usually do is using a config file for production

add a prod.conf file in /conf

```
# this include all your standard configuration
include "application.conf"

# you override this key
play.http.secret.key=abcdefghij
```

for production run with `-Dconfig.file=conf/prod.conf`

Comment: tired and it's throwing the same error. BTW adding prod.conf is not mandatory, It will override the application.conf if you provide prod.conf.

Comment: the include at the top of prod.conf is here to allow extension instead of override. If this doesn't work, a piece of information should be missing : how to you launch your server ? You use sbt right ?

Comment: Initially, I was using activator command but now I gave up and using `sbt run`. Using `sbt` works for me. I am still worried why `activator` command stopped working.

Comment: the reason is probably that activator is no longer supported : https://www.lightbend.com/blog/introducing-a-new-way-to-get-started-with-lightbend-technologies-and-saying-goodbye-to-activator

Answer (score 0):

You must to change your secret key, "abcdefghij" is by default but play not allow to keep this value of secret key. you can put what you want.